# Oracle Procedure to Copy data view into table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I would need to copy or insert data from `my_view` (that is based on 3 joined tables). Before that, I've created table `my_table` based on `my_view` .
For the procedure I've used the below :

```
create or replace procedure view_copy(
            my_view in varchar2, 
            my_table in varchar2)
is
begin
     execute immediate 'insert into '||my_table||' (select * from '||my_view||')';
end;
```

The data are not copied to `my_table`. Is it possible to copy data from view to table? How can I write the procedure differently?

Comment: Of course it is allowed.  But if you don't specify the columns, then your SQL is probably generating an error.

Comment: Would a materialized view work instead of a view? Then you would not need to copy from the view to a table.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure works; if you can't find data in your target table, maybe you should check your view.
A simple test on your procedure:

```
SQL> create table table1 ( id1 number)
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> create table table2 ( id2 number)
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> create or replace view v_t1_t2 as select id1, id2 from table1 cross join table2
  2  /

View created.

SQL> create table table1_2 ( id1 number, id2 number)
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure view_copy(
  2              my_view in varchar2,
  3              my_table in varchar2)
  4  is
  5  begin
  6       execute immediate 'insert into '||my_table||' (select * from '||my_view||')';
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> insert into table1 values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table2 values (2);

1 row created.

SQL> exec view_copy('v_t1_t2', 'table1_2');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from table1_2;

       ID1        ID2
---------- ----------
         1          2
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to write the procedure without 'execute immediate ' -rather with dbms_output.put_line to see whether the data has been inserted or not ?

Comment: If you need to really execute the `insert`, you need `execute immediate` ( or similar solutions); if you only want to view the statement, you can use `dbms_output`, but this will not insert in table, only show you the statement